# Celery tasks pending while workers are available

Tags: python, parallel-processing, celery

I have the following scenario:
I'm launching a first task (let's call it the parent task). This parent task then uses `group` to queue some children tasks. I need the return values of those children tasks and I would rather treat them as they come instead of waiting for all the children tasks to end, so I'm using a `join` on the result set returned by `group`, with the `callback` argument.

However, what happens is that, most of the time, a part of the children tasks stays in a pending state - while there are workers doing nothing - and the parent tasks runs forever. This seems to happen regardless of the number of workers.

Am I misunderstanding something about Celery? I would think that this should not happen and available workers should start treating those tasks.
Or is it that the children tasks not run are queued to be run by the same worker running the parent task? In that case, what could I do?

Comment: It is possible that the child tasks are prefetched onto the parent worker.  If this is the case you can set the prefetch multiplier to 1 to help reduce this.  The other question I have is do you have any named queues that the children are going to.

Comment: @user2097159 I'd rather not set the prefetch multiplier to 1, but that could be a temporary fix if that is indeed the problem. Also, I'm not manually managing queues at the moment.

Comment: It may be worth manually managing the queues if you have long and short running tasks.  You should look into something like flower to monitor your workers and their queues.

Comment: @user2097159 I'll try to look into that, thanks.

Comment: @user2097159 link to 'flower'?

Comment: https://github.com/mher/flower